# PHP Fatal error : Class 'DOMPDF' not found on line 30

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

I am using DOMPDF to generate PDFs from HTML.
I have copied all required files from github (encoding branch). But it says class DOMPDF not error as below.

link for dompdf_config.inc.php in gitbub : https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/tree/encoding

**Here is my code :**

```
require_once("APIs/dompdf-encoding/dompdf_config.inc.php");     
$cart_body='<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /><title>New Order Placed</title></head><body><p>Test Printing...</p></body></html>';
        $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
        $dompdf->load_html($cart_body);//body -> html content which needs to be converted as pdf..
        $dompdf->render();
        $dompdf->stream("sample.pdf"); //To popup pdf as download
```

**Actual Output is :**

> Fatal error: Class 'DOMPDF' not found in /home/web/www/test_dompdf.php
>   on line 30

Line 30 is  `$dompdf = new DOMPDF();`

**Note:** Other Master Branch is working fine. I need this encoding branch as it solves encoding font related issues.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've tested your code and it works fine for me - sample.pdf file is being downloaded in browser. I've downloaded library from https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/releases/tag/v0.6.1 url (not only the encoding branch(

Probably you haven't moved the whole project to selected directory or you haven't downloaded the whole library.  I moved the whole downloaded directory content to `APIs/dompdf-encoding` directory and I have here files `dompdf_config.inc.php` and directories `lib`, `include` and `www`.

**EDIT**

As you edited you want to use only encoding branch, what you have to do is adding the following code at the beginning of your file:

```
use Dompdf\Adapter\CPDF;
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Exception;
```

**EDIT2**

The whole working code:

```
<?php
use Dompdf\Adapter\CPDF;
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Exception;



        require_once("APIs/dompdf-encoding/dompdf_config.inc.php");     
$cart_body='<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /><title>New Order Placed</title></head><body><p>Test Printing...</p></body></html>';
        $dompdf = new Dompdf();
        $dompdf->load_html($cart_body);//body -> html content which needs to be converted as pdf..
        $dompdf->render();
        $dompdf->stream("sample.pdf"); //To popup pdf as download
```

I have also changed `DOMPDF` to `Dompdf` just in case (in Windows both are working)

Comment: where is the vendor folder ? i dont see anything inside

Comment: You need to install Composer and use it. Simple look at `http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md` url as in comment above from DomPDF example

Comment: if i set DOMPDF_ENABLE_AUTOLOAD to False , then dont i need to install the autoload ?

Comment: You can probably try to include also at the beginning this file: `https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/encoding/include/autoload.inc.php` (of course with your server structure). In this case those 2 above line shouldn't be necessary (but I haven't tested it)

Comment: i just checked the config file : `def("DOMPDF_ENABLE_AUTOLOAD", true);if (DOMPDF_ENABLE_AUTOLOAD) {
  require_once(DOMPDF_INC_DIR . "/autoload.inc.php");
  require_once(DOMPDF_LIB_DIR . "/php-font-lib/classes/Font.php");
}` so the file is already called. I think something else is the issue

Comment: Please look at my changed answer

Comment: I know it will work. even it was working for me when i download v0.6.1 code alone. How did you merge encoding version code and v0.6.1 code together ? becuase i need encoding branch code as it has encoding related issues solved.

Comment: I haven't merged anything. I have simple downloaded v0.6.1 and it works fine

Comment: ya., i dont want that one. i want encoding branch as it has font encoding related issues resolved. !

Comment: In Which file I need to add those lines ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56581/discussion-between-logan-and-marcin-nabialek).

Comment: Thanks. it worked. but UT8 characters are not getting printed. Can you please try printing this html ? `$cart_body=<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>New Order Placed</title>
  </head>
  <body><p>தமிழ் முந்திரி </p></body>
  </html>`

Comment: It doesn't work for me either. I get `?` signs. I haven't found any solution for this.

Comment: ya.. I am actually looking to print those characters.. Do you know any other HTML to PDF converter in market ?

Comment: I solve the proble by putting `
use Dompdf\Dompdf; ` on the top of my php file before any `inlude` statement .

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for version 2.0.2.

```
<?php
    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    
    use Dompdf\Dompdf;
    
    $html =
        '<html><body>' .
        '<p>Put your html here, or generate it with your favourite ' .
        'templating system.</p>' .
        '</body></html>';
    
    $dompdf = new Dompdf();
    $dompdf->loadHtml($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    $output = $dompdf->output();
    file_put_contents('/tmp/Brochure.pdf', $output);
```