# require(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, dompdf, codeigniter-4

I have been porting my project to CodeIgniter4 from CodeIgniter3 for some time now. I am now at the stage where I would like to spew out some information in PDF. I used to use dompdf library in CI3 without any problems. I have hit a concrete wall in CI4.

I went through the step 1 to 4 as explained in [this tutorial](https://www.nicesnippets.com/blog/codeigniter-4-pdf-tutorial) with the following deviations

In the app/Config/Autoload.php, I registered the dompdf service this way:

```
public $psr4 = [
    APP_NAMESPACE => APPPATH, // For custom app namespace
    'Config'      => APPPATH . 'Config',
    //'Dompdf'    => APPPATH . 'ThirdParty/dompdf/src',
    //not like this ^^^
    'Dompdf'      => APPPATH . 'ThirdParty/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src', <-- like this
];
```

and my controller looks like this

```
<?php
namespace App\ThirdParty;
namespace App\Controllers;

use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use CodeIgniter\Controller;

class AjaxDomPDF extends Controller
{
  function htmlToPDF($view){
    $dompdf = new \Dompdf\Dompdf();
    $dompdf->loadHtml(view($view));
    $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream();
  }
}
```

and my route entry in app/Config/Routes.php file is

```
$routes->get('generatePDF/(:segment)', 'AjaxDomPDF::htmlToPDF/$1');
```

With this arragement, I get the error

> Class 'Dompdf\Cpdf' not found

I foraged and [the best solution seemed to be this](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/919) and therefore I edited my controller to like as follows

```
<?php
namespace App\ThirdParty;
namespace App\Controllers;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'vendor/dompdf/dompdf/lib/Cpdf.php';

use Dompdf\Dompdf;
// disable DOMPDF's internal autoloader if you are using Composer
define('DOMPDF_ENABLE_AUTOLOAD', false);
define("DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE", true);

// include DOMPDF's default configuration
require_once 'vendor/dompdf/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php';

use CodeIgniter\Controller;

class AjaxDomPDF extends Controller
{
  function htmlToPDF($view){
    $dompdf = new \Dompdf\Dompdf();
    $dompdf->loadHtml(view($view));
    $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream();
  }
}
```

With this I now get the error

> require(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I foraged and found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41209349/requirevendor-autoload-php-failed-to-open-stream/41209642) but no answer there, so far, seem to address my problem.

Comment: How did you install these packages? Using `composer install`?

Comment: Yes! I used composer. I issued the command 'composer require dompdf/dompdf'

Comment: And what have you tried to resolve the error? Where were these files installed?

Comment: I am stuck completely! I can't figure out why the parser says the file is not there. The path given is correct, the file is there.

Comment: I bumped into [a similar problem for someone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37831516/dompdf-with-codeigniter) and noticed that they were pre-pending the APPPATH constant to the relative paths to the files mentioned in the controller. And this worked! So
> require 'vendor/autoload.php';
becomes
> require APPPATH.'vendor/autoload.php';

Now I don't consider this the answer because I don't know why the clearly correct relative paths do not work. If someone can explain this, that should be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you run this command (`composer require dompdf/dompdf`) in the root directory of your Codeigniter site then you only need to change DomPdf path in the **app/Config/Autoload.php** file from **APPPATH . 'ThirdParty/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src'** to **'/vendor/dompdf/src'** like this:

```
public $psr4 = [
    APP_NAMESPACE => APPPATH, // For custom app namespace
    'Config'      => APPPATH . 'Config',
    'Dompdf'    =>  '/vendor/dompdf/src',
];
```

**Explanation:**
When you run a `composer` command the **Composer** create (or update the content if already exist) a ***vendor*** directory in the current directory (where you entered in command line before execute any `composer` command) and downloads the requirements into this directory.

**UPDATE:**

When you execute a `composer` command this create or update **own vendor directory** in current directory. So firstly you create a new CI4 project by Composer with following command:
`composer create-project codeigniter4/appstarter`

---

Then the Composer also create a "config" directory to itself for the current environment that includes classmaps, PSR-4 autoloads, etc... Now in the **vendor/composer** directory there is a **autoload_psr4.php** file which generated when command executed. This file contains all of requirements (both of `composer require <example>` and found at `"require"`-block in **composer.json** file.

---

Now in the **/project-root-directory/vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php** file contains the *Codeigniter* namespace!
After that -- because you wrote -- your **Dompdf** library and its requirements found in **/project-root-directory/app/ThirdParty/vendor/**. This is possible if you execute the next command inside the **/app/ThirdParty/** directory:
`composer require dompdf/dompdf`

And when appears the following question, you pressed **n** as **No**.
`No composer.json in current directory, do you want to use the one at /project-root-directory? [Y,n]?`

Otherwise the **Dompdf** and its requirements installed into 1st-level vendor directory in project-root.

---

When you execute the command above, in the **app/ThirdParty/vendor/** directory contains **only!** the **Dompdf** and its requirements and nothing else therefore you can load the **Codeigniter\Controller** class with `use CodeIgniter\Controller;` but the `use Dompdf\Dompdf;` not working, because the **Dompdf** vendor directory is not same as **Codeigniter framework** vendor directory therefore can not communicate to each other.

Comment: Sorry you are not answering the question... with everything else staying constant, i.e. no change(s) to app/Config/Autoload.php from what I have stated above, my problem was solved simply by pre-pending the constant APPPATH to the relative CORRECT PATHS in the CONTROLLER. Why? Why are these CORRECT PATHS (in the CONTROLLER) not working unless we pre-pend them with the constant, APPPATH? The question has now degraded to this?

Comment: Iys your **app/ThirdParty** directory contains the **vendor** directory and that is contains the **dompdf** directory?

Comment: @owino The tutorial which you linked as first is correct, but I think the author forgot to leave a warning that he/she redirected the **vendor** directory to the **app/ThirdParty** location

Comment: Yes, if you use composer to install, like I did, the app/ThirdParty directory contains the vendor directory. The path to the dompdf files is  app/ThirdParty/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/